# Setting icon on a Mac with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, icons

As described in the Qt-Documentation I have created my icon file with the icon-composer. Then I have inserted in my .pro-file the following line.

```
ICON = 3D_Modell.icns
```

While compiling I get the following error:

```
No rule to make target `../3D', needed by `3D_Modell.app/Contents/Resources/3D_Modell.icns'
```

Where is the Contents/Resources folder?
Where exactly do I put the icns-file. I have put it into the folder where my project and all cpp and h files lie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [instructions](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/appicon.html#setting-the-application-icon-on-mac-os-x) suggest you can add the icon manually:

> 1. Create an Info.plist file for your application (using the
>      PropertyListEditor, found in Developer/Applications).
> 2. Associate your .icns record with the CFBundleIconFile record in the Info.plist file
>      (again, using the PropertyListEditor).
> 3. Copy the Info.plist file into your application bundle's Contents directory.
> 4. Copy the .icns file into your application bundle's Contents/Resources directory.

To get access to your application bundle from the finder, **right-click on your application and select 'show package contents'** from the context menu. This will open a new finder window from which you can navigate to `/Contents/Resources/`.

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

The PropertyListEditor utility is in `Developer/Applications/Utilities/`. You can use it to "open" your application bundle, and edit the plist (located in the bundle's `/Contents/` folder). The `CFBundleIconFile` item is helpfully called `Icon File` in the editor, but if you select View > Show Raw Keys/Values you can see the actual property names.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am trying to follow the steps, but the I dont understand the second step. How do I associate my icns.record with CFBundleIconFile. Where do i find this CFBundleIconFile.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please consider accepting my answer (by clicking on the big tick-mark), thanks.

Comment: If you are using `qmake`, as is the normal Qt build process, the manual steps should be unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you its working. I thought that I also needed to add the line ICON = xxxx.icns into the pro. But it isnt necessary, when creating the icon with plist. Thanks again.

Comment: in qt creator 4.2.1 & Qt 5.8 this work for me: 1. remove the build folder with finder, 2. in .pro as usual ICON=myapp.icns and build, it's important to first remove the complete folder.

Answer (score 5):

All we have in our `.pro` file is:

```
macx:ICON = $${PWD}/my_app.icns
```

The icon is in the same directory as the `.pro` file. No manual steps are necessary.

Comment: Additionally, I use QMAKE_INFO_PLIST = Info.plist line and I need to add manually     <key>CFBundleIconFile</key> <string>AppIcon</string> values to the info.plist file.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an issue with the icon name. Try Modell.icns instead.